# Whats the value, of one week, in a long?

Tags: java, long-integer

I want to take 2 long values, `System.currentTimeMillis()` compared to a pre-recorded long.

I want to see if the larger - the smaller is greater than or equal to the value of a week.

But whats the value of a week in a long?

Comment: In sidereal time? Solar/synodic time?

Comment: @TheZ - I'm pretty sure, the concept of *a week* is only known on earth... One could define a *day* for every rotating object in space (the moon doesn't have a day ;)) but the definition of seven days being equal to one day has some earth-exclusive religious tradition ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we're talking milliseconds, then [Google has the answer for us](https://www.google.ca/search?q=milliseconds+in+a+week&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

`604800000 ms`.

Comment: @RobbyCatron I feel stupid plenty of times throughout the day. Don't feel too bad. :)

Comment: Ok i have another stupid question just because i havent had my coffee yet :P
If i pre-recorded the date using `System.currentTimeMillis()` , a few days ago... Which would i do first in the subtraction?

`System.currentTimeMillis() - oldDateValue >= aWeek`
or `oldDateValue - System.currentTimeMillis() >= aWeek` ?

Comment: @RobbyCatron If you have another question, you should ask it in a new question- that way you'll get more exposure to it and it will be searchable. Also, if you have been helped by my answer, make sure to accept it when 15 minutes has elapsed.

Answer (score 4):

7 days, 24 hours, 60 min, 60 second, 1000 millis and most importantly `L` for long

```
long millisForAWeek = 7*24*60*60*1000L
```

Comment: This is good because it can be easier to change the value (if we listen to the Beatles' song Eight Days a Week, or decide we only want to report minutes, or if suddenly there are only 57 seconds in each minute). And I think it becomes clearer for others how the number was reached.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Date.setDate() is deprecated, I tried the following,

```
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(now); //'now' being the 14th of the month
    Date day = new Date();
    System.out.println(day);
    day.setDate(21); // one week later
    long day2 = day.getTime();
    System.out.println(day2); 

    long week = day2-now;
    System.out.println(week);
```

with the following results

> Tue Aug 14 11:26:34 CDT 2012
>   1345566394008
>   604800000